# Using bagging and random forests together

Tags: python, random-forest, boosting, bagging

I was looking at a kernel implementation (for text classification) and the following piece of code got me a little bit confused (I removed part of the features - in order to keep it light - as most of them are similar - e.g. number of negative, positive, neutral words):

```
pipeline_ = Pipeline([
    ('fu', FeatureUnion([
        ('tfdif_features', Pipeline([
            ('cv', CountVectorizer()),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
            ('tfidf_', Wrapper(RandomForestClassifier())),
        ])),
        ('nb_pos_features', Pipeline([
            ('nb_pos', NumberSelector('posWords') ),
            ('nb_pos_', Wrapper(RandomForestClassifier())),
        ])),
    ])),
    ('xgb', XGBClassifier()),
])
```

At first I thought that it looks like bagging, as for each feature a base model is created, followed by boosting. But isn't the Random Forest in this case a Decision Tree? Why using Random Forest and not something else (e.g. Logistic regression)?

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I think you are asking about the difference between a CART, a logistic regression, a RF, and a sequential learner comprised of two random forests that input into a gradient boosted tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But isn't the Random Forest in this case a Decision Tree?

All random forest models are ensembles of decision trees. Random forest constructs many decision trees using a randomization procedure.

> Why using Random Forest and not something else (e.g. Logistic regression)?

Because the author of this code made a deliberate choice. You'll have to ask the author why they chose Random Forest instead of a different method. Generically, tree induction methods like random forest are very flexible, whereas logistic regression is merely a linear model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @moz_szt if you’ve found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. More information about how the site works can be found in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

What the model is intending to do is use the output of **RandomForest1** and **RandomForest2** as features into the **XGBoost** Classifier

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood that part, but I didn't quite understood why using a Random Forest for only one feature? Why not using Logistic Regression or something else?

Comment: @moz_szt, the TFIDF vectorizer will translate each row to multiple features. It is not a single feature.